# Why there is no zoom in and out slots in QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, text-editor, qtextedit

I noticed that a [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtextedit.html) has zoom in and zoom out slots and using them is very easy. However, I am using a widget that inherits from [QPlainTextEdit](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qplaintextedit.html) and QPlainTextEdit has none of them which seems weird to me. I think these two widgets are do the similar jobs.

How can i implement the zoom in and out feature in my widget (which inherits QPlainTextEdit)? Is inheriting both qplaintextedit and qtextedit a good solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why won't you inherit Only from QTextEdit?

Comment: i am implementing a simple code editor, so i considered qplaintextedit is more suitable for it. am i right? or is qtextedit is more convenient.

Comment: It already has a zoom feature. Try Ctrl+MouseWheel. If you need manual control of it, then you should use QTextEdit.

Comment: thanks for advices, i switched to qtextedit but, this time i lost the advantages of qplaintextedit such as textblock related member functions :((

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest multiply inheriting from two different qt text editors, that is a dangerous game. If you need the functionality inherent to the QTextEdit, you should inherit only from this.